# Is deploying to a hosting provider required for standalone Blazor webassembly PWA?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a Blazor(PWA) standalone app.  Is deploying to a hosting provider required for standalone Blazor webassembly PWA?  Or is it possible to serve the app from a network location for users to download and run it locally in their browser?  I looked for documentation but can't find any.  Please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to host the app from an HTTP server that provides secure hosting (HTTPS). For example, you could set up an HTTP server on your local network, or use a hosting provider on the internet.

It cannot be shared from a network drive, or anything like that because it's not considered secure, and thus the service worker won't be registered.

Comment: Thank you!  I was under the impression that a PWA app works like a mobile app with no hosting required.

Comment: Think of it this way, the first time you install a mobile app, you need to install it from somewhere, Play Store or App Store. PWAs are similar, first time you need to install it, it needs to come from a server. The same story exists if you want to update it, for apps, you need to get the updates from the Store, and for PWAs, the updates come from the server.